# change div0 error into a value (getting error 13) vba excel

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

there's cells that have div 0 error because some values hasn't been updated yet, so here's what i wrote to workaround that (triying to change values inside the array):

```
For a = 0 To cap

    Hoja9.Cells(a + 4, 3).Value = Empty
    array_visco(a, 0) = Hoja1.Range("C" & a + 2)


   If Hoja1.Range("C" & a + 2) = CVErr(xlErrDiv0) Then array_visco(a, 0) = 0
' ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^ i get error 13 in this line  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^

    'menor quexxx
    Select Case Hoja9.Cells(2, 3)
    Case Is > 0
    If array_visco(a, 0) <= Hoja9.Cells(2, 3) Then Hoja9.Cells(a + 4, 3) = array_visco(a, 0)
    End Select
    'mayor quexxxx
    Select Case Hoja9.Cells(1, 3)
    Case Is > 0
    If array_visco(a, 0) >= Hoja9.Cells(1, 3) Then Hoja9.Cells(a + 4, 3) = array_visco(a, 0)
    End Select
    If Hoja9.Cells(a + 4, 3) = Empty Then Hoja9.Cells(a + 4, 3) = CVErr(xlErrNA)



    Next
```

problem is that i get error 13 and i dont know why

---

SOLUTION:

thanks to Jeeped

change this line

```
If Hoja1.Range("C" & a + 2) = CVErr(xlErrDiv0) Then array_visco(a, 0) = 0
```

to

```
Select Case Hoja1.Range("C" & (a + 2)).Text
Case Is = "#¡DIV/0!"
array_visco(a, 0) = 0
End Select
```

Comment: error '13': Type mismatch: not sure, but .Range("C" & a + 2) should be .Range("C" & (a + 2)) or perhaps CVErr(xlErrDiv0) returns other variable type then .Range("C" & a + 2)

Comment: should not be a problem, but i tried that  and same error in the same line

Comment: try to print out or debug the values of : CVErr(xlErrDiv0) , Hoja1.Range("C" & a + 2): cverr give the error number 2007 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb211091(v=office.12).aspx) perhaps try VarType(Hoja1.Range("C" & a + 2)) <> vbError

Comment: i just want to change that error and overwrite it by a  random value inside the array,
all the variables seem normal, i tried to change the statement using selet case,`Select Case Hoja1.Range("C" & (a + 2)) Case Is = CVErr(xlErrDiv0) array_visco(a, 0) = 0 End Select` now the line that that's pointed out is `Case Is = CVErr(xlErrDiv0)`, still dont know why, everything seems normal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the error on a cell that is **not** a `#DIV/0!` error; not on one that **is** a `#DIV/0!` (or any other) error.

Here is one method of checking for any worksheet error and then two that only check for `#DIV/0!` errors.

```
If IsError(Selection) Then
    Debug.Print "iserror"
End If
If Selection.Text = "#DIV/0!" Then
    Debug.Print "text found error"
End If
If Selection = CVErr(xlErrDiv0) Then
    Debug.Print "xlErrDiv0"
End If
```

The third method can identify errors when there is an error but produces a `Type mismatch` when there isn't one. A regular text, date or number value cannot be compared to an error any more than an error can be assigned to a string or integer.

The second method of simply comparing the [Range.Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx) may be the best method of locating `#DIV/0!` specific errors and the first will catch any `#DIV/0!`, `#VALUE!`, `#N/A`, etc errors.

Comment: jesus, yeah the second one did the trick, thank you very much this thing was going make me mad, going to edit my question to post the solution.